# css control alignment issue

Tags: css, forms, layout

I am trying to align label : control, label: control in 2 rows. [image]

But text in my 2nd row moves to little bit right as below image. How can I align label and control in same line for second row also? These are generic forms so I dont want to add any **height** added to class. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[Here is my Code](http://jsfiddle.net/GkZ3b/)

```
<div class="editor-label"><label for="DocumentSignature">This is a test label with big text below and below</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Document Signature Services Request URL field is required." id="DocumentSignature" name="DocumentSignature" type="text" value=""> 
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DocumentSignature" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="DealSummary">This is next div text which moved to right</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Deal Summary Template URL field is required." id="DealSummary" name="DealSummary" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DealSummary" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>


.editor-label {
    max-width: 150px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 14pt;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    line-height: 22pt;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    }

.editor-field {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 22pt;
    font-size: 10pt;
    clear: right;    
}
.label {
    width: 180px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see here for [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VLeP6/)

You have to wrap single row with one parent `div` and then clear all `float` at that `div`.

HTML:

```
<div class='single_row'>
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="DocumentSignature">This is a test label with big   text below and below</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Document Signature Services Request URL field is required." id="DocumentSignature" name="DocumentSignature" type="text" value="" /> 
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DocumentSignature" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
</div>

<div class='single_row'>
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="DealSummary">This is next div text which moved to right</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Deal Summary Template URL field is required." id="DealSummary" name="DealSummary" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DealSummary" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.editor-label {
    max-width: 150px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 14pt;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    line-height: 22pt;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    }

.single_row{ clear:both;}

.editor-field {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 22pt;
    font-size: 10pt;
    clear: right;    
}
.label {
    width: 180px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a container that will contain both `.editor-field` and `.editor-label`. Without this, it will be very difficult if not impossible to make then work together.

```
<div class="editor-element">
    <div class="editor-label">...</div>
    <div class="editor-field">...</div>
</div>
```

Make this container "contain" the floated elements, so either add `overflow: hidden`, some kind of `float` or clearfix to it:

```
.editor-element {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GkZ3b/2/)